# Spring Cloud Config Dynamic Vault Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am converting my Spring Boot apps to use Spring Cloud Config (SCC). I would like to use it with a GIT and VAULT backend. This is easily set up and it works by accepting a Vault token when the client apps call it for properties.

This won't work in my case since our vault tokens expire after some short TTL.

I want a solution that will allow us to restart our apps and when that happens, they simply call SCC and get all their props (including secrets from vault). This is further confused by the fact that we use approle for our VAULT app. Though even with approle, our secret token changes and times out.

What I want to build is something in all our client apps that will do the dance with Vault to get our approle token, or the regular token (both can be achieved with 2 simple POST methods to Vault) and then pass that token on to the SCC client code when we call to get our properties.

This is hard but not super hard. It requires either hacking into the spring boot bootstrap context (see : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/1.3.x/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_customizing_the_bootstrap_configuration) or hacking SCC itself.

If I dig into the SCC github (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config) I find that there is a pretty clear call to org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientProperties when SCC client calls to the server to get properties.

My idea is that I can override this class with my own so that when SCC asks for a vault token with ConfigClientProperties.getToken() I can make my calls to vault and then dynamically get a token.

I just don't know how to override this class elegantly.

My question in two related parts :

1) Is this the best way to accomplish this?
2) How could I cleanly inject my own dynamic config class into SCC client?

Thanks in advance!